# Como Obtengo el Registro Máximo de una tabla SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net

Necesito el ultimo registro (`MAX`) de la tabla usuarios, el dato mayor del campo n y darle este dato máximo a la variable `num`

```
myconn.Open()
        Try
            sqlquery = "select MAX(n)as nom from usuario"
            myReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader()
            myReader.Read()
            num = myReader("nom")
            MessageBox.Show(num)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        myconn.Close()
```

Comment: @A.Cedano no entiendo porque es necesario usar GROUP BY en un MAX, incluso si el MAX se repitiera, solo está trayendo una sola columna (?)

Comment: @A.Cedano no me muestra ningun error, solo no aparece el num max dentro de la variable

Comment: @Sr1871 tienes razón, retiro mi comentario. Inusui, ¿qué sale en la variable entonces?

Comment: tal parece que tiene error en el sql por tanto no ejecuta el messagebox.show(num)

Comment: En la lógica de tu código nunca se pasa la consulta SQL. Deberías tener algo como esto: **`mycmd = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, myconn)`** . Debes ponerlo **antes** de esta línea: `myReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader()`. También, puedes dejar la consulta así: `select MAX(n) as nom from usuario`, no hace falta `GROUP BY` como sugería antes. Y pon la palabra `as`  separada, no da error, pero debes respetar los espacios.

Comment: Además de lo que acertadamente te dice @A.Cedano, para obtener un único resultado como es una consulta con `max`, es mucho mejor que utilices `ExecuteScalar` en lugar de utilizar un `SqlDataReader`

Comment: @Pikoh dado que por lo visto conoces sobre `vb.net` (yo nunca he programado en ese lenguaje), algo que me extraña es que usando un `try ... catch` su código no levante una excepción en este caso. Pregunto sólo por curiosidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano no creo que no esté levantando excepción. Lo que pasa es que el `catch` está vacio, asi que lo captura y se lo traga sin lanzar ningun mensaje. No tiene ningun sentido, obviamente :)

Comment: @Pikoh entonces quizá sea bueno sugerirle que imprima un mensaje con la excepción en el  `catch`, supongo que ¿sería con algo como esto: `MessageBox.Show(ex)`?, de ese modo estaría viendo en pantalla el motivo exacto del error.

Comment: @A.Cedano efectivamente, lo minimo exigible en un `Catch` sería un `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` para recibir algo de información de la excepción